# Произношение иноязычных фамилий

Tags: орфоэпия, фонетика, ономастика, фамилии

Фамилии типа *Вольтер*, *Флобер* и др. мы произносим, не смягчая согласный звук перед Е: *Вольт[э]р*, *Флоб[э]р*. Но почему-то фамилии типа *Менакер* или *Каннегисер* все произносят со смягчением. Почему? Потому что ударение не на эту Е, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Нашла очень весёлую [рекомендацию](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=12):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть надо всего-навсего определить, твёрдый или мягкий согласный предшествует проблемночитаемой ***е***. (Уже можно-таки смеяться.)

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=8,2#pp8), к которому отсылают рекомендатели, суров, но он - закон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть он просит: ребяты, проверяйте и выучивайте, и всё тут.

Ещё, [современное, подробное,](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook083/01/part-004.htm) на бис:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, всё по словарю и наизусть.

---

[Информация](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6388) к размышлению:

> По какой причине так сложилось, что на конце заимствованных слов и
> имён собственных согласные перед "Е" (кроме Г, К, Л, Х) почти всегда
> произносятся твёрдо *(купе, кафе, Актобе, шоссе, шимпанзе, тире,
> Джузеппе, Скорсезе* и т.д.), за редкими исключениями, наблюдающимися
> только в безударной позиции *(кофе, бреве, Пле́ве)*? И сколько всего
> таких исключений встречается на практике?

Возможно (хотя и не доказано), что дело таки да, в безударной позиции.

Answer (score 0):

Ольга, прежде всего здесь нет и не может быть каких-то универсальных правил. Не ищите объяснений тому, что их не имеет.

Не знаю, где вы услышали подобные рекомендации, но Флобер давно уже произносят со смягчением. Вообще каждое произношение индивидуально, но в целом все они постепенно приходят к русскому варианту, со смягчением.

В целом подмечено, что медленнее идет процесс смягчения у фамилий (и вообще заимствований), где сильнее оппозиция в русском (например в сочетании с зубными Т и Д прежде всего), быстее - с заднеязычными (К, Г, Х).

Это частично объясняет ваши примеры. Остальное - надо разбирать индивидуально.

> Потому что ударение не на этот Е, что ли?

Так оно в оригинале, если считать фамилии французскими, везде на последний слог падает в ваших примерах. )))) Вы что-то совсем не то подумали. Тут еще имеет некоторый смысл смотреть, насколько обрусела фамилия и из какого языка пришла (немецкие фамилии часто допускают смягчение даже в оригинале, французские - нет), но никак не ударения.

Comment: Проще говоря, Флобер и Вольтер — французские фамилии, и они не смягчаются, а Каннегисер и Менакер больше подвержены обрусению как немецкие. Вы упоминали, что немецкие фамилии в оригинале допускают смягчение? Приведите примеры, если можно, а то я как-то совсем таких не припоминаю.

Comment: @Ольга Гете.пойдет? Рентген. Кейтель. - все заднеязычные изначально мягкие. *...французские фамилии, и они не смягчаются...* - вы не совсем верно передали мою мысль.

Comment: ***В оригинале*** они вовсе даже не смягчаются. Вообще в немецком мягкий только L да ещё согласный перед умлаутом, не мне Вас здесь учить...

Comment: Засомневался с Флобером. Хотя Розенталь однозначно пишет, что "**Твердое произнесение согласных перед е рекомендуется в** иноязычных собственных именах: Белла, Бизе, Вольтер: Декарт, Доде, Жорес, Кармен, Мери, Пастер, Роден, **Флобер**, Шопен, Аполлинер, Фернандель [дэ?], Картер, Ионеско, Минелли, Ванесса Редгрейв, Сталлоне и др." (§239)